# nodejs Sequelize bulkCreate() model error validation not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have multiple data insert operations in my application

and when i use bulkCreate then it works for me

but I have an issue that when some required field like name which is not null in the database and i call create or save method for an individual method without name then it gives the error: required validation error

but when i do the same in bulkCreate then it creates with null value without throwing an error

following is the code of bulkCreate which is not working

```
models.testModel.bulkCreate(postObj.evUserFavouriteLocations,{updateOnDuplicate: true}).then(function (result) {
    console.log("postObj.");
}).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function (err) {
console.log(' in sequierererror', err);
}).catch(function (err) {
console.log("err::",err);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For `bulkCreate`, validation is turn off by default. You need to pass `validate: true` in order for validation to work.

Read the document here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting ignoreDuplicates option to true.
E.g. Model.bulkCreate(dataArray, {ignoreDuplicates: true})